# SQL Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following SQL table:

```
CarId | CustomerId | Price  
 1    |     1      | 5000  
 2    |     3      | 6000  
 3    |     4      | 6000  
 4    |     1      | 6000  
 5    |     3      | 6000  
 6    |     6      | 6000
```

I want to create a new column:

```
CarId | CustomerId | Price | CarPerCustomer
 1    |     1      | 5000  |       1/2
 2    |     3      | 6000  |       1/3
 3    |     4      | 6000  |       1/1
 4    |     1      | 6000  |       2/2
 5    |     3      | 6000  |       2/3
 6    |     3      | 6000  |       3/3
```

So basically CarPerCustomer = number of row/(Total number of cars owned by this customer). Anyone?

Comment: Is it supposed to be a query result or persistent table with persistent column?

Comment: How to get 'Number of Row' and 'Total number of cars owned' ?

Comment: You appear to have a typo in the numbering scheme of your desired output, but I won't edit it.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I want to add it to a stored procedure

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Fixed! Thanks

Comment: @NicolasJamal not fixed :) following logic from your question for `carid = 4` and `CustomerId = 1` there must be `2/2` in `CarPerCustomer`

Comment: Anyway, you got 3 working answers :)

Comment: @gofr1 Yes! Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use window functions

```
select CarId, CustomerId, Price
    , cast(row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by CustomerId) as varchar)
        + '/' + cast(count(*) over (partition by CustomerId ) as varchar)
    from t
```

Comment: Nice one! Just add `cast to nvarchar` for `row_number()` and `count`

Answer (score 0):

This query is a little bit tricky because you need to number the cars for each customer and this data does not exist in your table.  You can generate the car numbers using a subquery.  This gives the numerator of the `CarPerCustomer` column.  For the denominator, the second part of my query computes the total number of cars per customer.

```
SELECT t1.CarId, t1.CustomerId, t1.Price,
    CONCAT((SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM customers
            WHERE CarId < t1.CarId AND CustomerId = t1.CustomerId),
    '/', t2.numCars) AS CarPerCustomer
FROM customers t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CustomerId, COUNT(*) AS numCars
    FROM customers
    GROUP BY CustomerId
) t2
    ON t1.CustomerId = t2.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  y.*, 
        CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY CarId) AS nvarchar(10)) 
        + '/' + 
        CAST(cars_per_cust AS nvarchar(10)) as CarPerCustomer
FROM YourTable y
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CarId) as cars_per_cust 
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE CustomerId = y.CustomerId
    ) p
ORDER BY CarId, CarPerCustomer
```

Output:

```
CarId       CustomerId  Price       CarPerCustomer
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------
1           1           5000        1/2
2           3           6000        1/3
3           4           6000        1/1
4           1           6000        2/2
5           3           6000        2/3
6           3           6000        3/3
```